# Neo4J Rest API comprehension

Tags: rest, neo4j, dart

I'm currently implementing the Neo4J Rest API for Dart language and I'm confuse with some APIs!

Concerning chapter 20.11.7, how can I build the URL http://yourhost.com:7474/db/data/label/Actor/nodes ? Ok for the last part of the URL but what about the first part (ie http://yourhost.com:7474/db/data/label). The service root does not return a link to labels' queries and I don't think that hard coded such a link is a good solution ;-)

I have the same problem with relationships "Get by ID" query 19.7.1 (http://yourhost.com:7474/db/data/relationship/30) : the service root answer does not return any link to query relationships (except using a node).

Don't you think there's some missing links from the service root answer ? Typically I would have add to the root's answer the following property:

```
{
"..." : "...",
"label" : "http://yourhost.com:7474/db/data/label",
"relationship" , "http://yourhost.com:7474/db/data/relationship",
"..." : "..."
}
```

Does anyone has already implemented these methods and how did you do?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: +1 for the "label" resource, as well as "schema/index/", since cypher doesn't have the alternative DDL statements for listing labels and label indexes (yet?)

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I would not bother with the REST API but rather use Cypher and the http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-cypher.html, since it supports al of the REST calls, except the handling of manual indexes.

Would that be an option?

Please keep us updated on your progress!

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answer.

Of course I'll also implement the Cypher part, but I'd like to implement all REST methods from chapter #19:
- transaction
- batch
- ...
Except if you say me : "Don't do that, you will waste your time and nobody use these methods !"

Comment: BTW: Currently 35% of REST methods are implemented. I hope to have a usable version start of January.